# C++: pass shared ptr by reference without breaking the sharing?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Suppose I use smart pointers? Ok, great:

```
shared_ptr<whatever>(new whatever());
```

Instantly, I want to do the following rather than tangle with C++'s single-return item policy and the semantic mess therein:

```
void do_something(whatever *& A, whatever *& B){
  auto Aptr = shared_ptr<whatever>(new whatever());
  A = Aptr.get();

  auto Bptr = shared_ptr<whatever>(new whatever());
  B = Bptr.get();
}
```

However, the shared_ptr mechanic deletes the objects as they are passed out of the function by reference so that, while the pointers in my calling code,

```
whatever *A,*B;
do_something(A,B);
```

Get set to the appropriate address by reference, the data has been obliterated.

---

All of this is to avoid the snarl of typing and documentation at the return type, as it is very natural to accumulate arguments in a list...but every additional item in the return tray splits context hinting across documentation.

Accessing values initialized by reference is altogether a desirable mechanic.

---

Also, I would like to add that I have gotten this mechanic to work, just so long as I own the pointers with the shared pointer in the calling scope.

However, this is a recursive repeat of the same problem: I would like to automatically manage the pointers inside the function and return them by reference to exterior variables, so that there is a look and feel of normal C pointers, but no mallocs or frees at the outer scope -- I just declare the pointers and pass them by reference.

Instead, I have 2 lines for every pointer: the declaration, the function that constructs their innards, and a shared ptr that owns them *after the function call.  Just another version of the malloc-free mechanic.

Ideally, there is a way to drop that second line where I own the ptr with a shared pointer, or (if that isn't possible), a way to initialize a shared pointer inside a function after declaring the pointer shared on the outside.  Note that the goal here is:

```
void func(double * a, int * b, T * c);

double *a; 
int *b; 
T *c;
func(a,b,c); 
// no headaches whatsoever at this scope.

// versus

double *a; 
int *b; 
T *c;
func(a,b,c);
shared_ptr<double> asp(a);
shared_ptr<int> bsp(b);
shared_ptr<T> csp(c,[](T*_){/*special T deletion process*/;};

// versus

double *a; 
int *b; 
T *c;
func(a,b,c);

/* solve the universe */

free(a);
free(b);
delete(T);
```

Comment: Use a multi-return value instead of out parameters.

Comment: Why not use return-values, compare http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-out. You can return a `struct` or a `pair`, even a `pair` of `shared_ptr`. BTW, why `shared_ptr`? Is a `unique_ptr` not sufficient?

Comment: I don't quite understand the purpose of "a look and feel of normal C pointers, but no mallocs or frees at the outer scope" - this will probably be equally confusing/suspicious to C and C++ programmers.

Comment: @Hulk the entire C++ universe is equally confusing and suspicious. your point is taken as an argument not to use C/C++ at all

Comment: @Hulk the point here is to control for the language semantics. Sure, the smart pointer reduces the likelihood of a memory error, but adds a layer of wrapped semantics and a bunch of code duplication.  The idea is to have a standard, and comply with it.

Comment: @Eljay The question is motivated by preference: I consider the raw types hinted at by an IDE combined with documentation inferior to a self-documenting variable name in a well namded function. All I desire is the ability to do away with lousy semantics.  This question is about achieving a coding style in some way, through some means.  The specifics are arbitrary, and it sounds like I have to use some library other than standard to do it.

Comment: @Eljay also, please see the second sentence of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be your problem can be solved by a structure with a constructor or two:

```
struct NoNeadachesWhatsoever {
    shared_ptr<double> asp;
    shared_ptr<int> bsp;
    shared_ptr<T> csp;

    NoNeadachesWhatsoever() {
        // initialize members.
    }
};

// ...

NoNeadachesWhatsoever no_headaches_whatsoever;
```

Comment: this is where I already am.  That is exactly what I have.  So the stack is as follows: a lower level C library, an upper level C++ extension that must and does work with raw pointers, and a C++ layer on top of that consisting of classes.  However, I would like to handle all of the memory issues at the C library interface. But, it appears, guaging by your response, that I must hold shared pointers in scope at the top level of whatever, and can only present the raw semantics of pointers via a private/public mechanic in the class that keeps the shared pointers in scope...safe to commit to this?

Comment: @Christopher You can extract a raw pointer from smart pointer and pass that to the C API.

Comment: @Christopher Smart pointers manage the lifetimes of objects, so that you need to keep the smart pointers alive when you still need the objects they manage. That is the sole purpose of smart pointers to manage the lifetimes for you, so that you don't need to clean up manually. Some useful reading https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.smartpointers

Comment: right, exactly.  The question amounts to: how does one share the ownership of the pointer to the ancestral scope by return or by reference so that the smart pointer semantics can be under the hood. otherwise, I am adding a thing that makes one task easier and another task harder by a roughly equal amount.  I believe QT smart pointers implementations can share the raw pointer to the outer scope as a raw pointer, and vanish for the purposes of the user...but that is hooked up into the QT object system.  The question is: can standard do this?

Comment: And yes, I am not confused at all about passing smart pointer's pointer object to a descendant.  I am attempting to pass the smart pointer's pointer to the ancestor scope.  Perhaps it helps if you know I have been programming professionally for 12 years, and this is an advanced question.  I already know that I can do this if I add QT to my project and inherit from QObject, using the Q shared pointer construct, but I'd rather use Standard.  Only it sounds like I can't do this with standard?

Comment: You can do smart->raw->smart with objects that embed the reference counter, see `boost::intrusive_ptr`. However, that risks maintaining the reference counter incorrectly and may lead to leaks or early destruction, which defeats the purpose of using smart pointers in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Just use shared pointers uniformly everywhere:

```
void do_something(std::shared_ptr<whatever> &A, std::shared_ptr<whatever> &B) {
           :
```

Comment: that's a lot of typing

Comment: If the typing bothers you too much,  define a shorter alias: `template<class T> using P<T> = std::shared_ptr<T>;`

Answer (score 0):

I have a bad answer, but it sould do what you want.

```
void do_something( whatever *& A, whatever *& B ) {
    static std::shared_ptr<whatever> ptr_a;
    static std::shared_ptr<whatever> ptr_b;
    ptr_a.reset( new whatever );
    ptr_b.reset( new whatever );
    A = ptr_a.get();
    B = ptr_b.get();
}
```

It will free your memory the next time you call the function, or when the program
ends, so depending on how much memory you need...

I thought I'd write it even if it's a bad answer.

A different answer that is not so bad would be having a class like this:

```
class Shallocator
{
public:
    Shallocator( whatever *& A, whatever *& B ) {
        ptr_a.reset( new whatever );
        ptr_b.reset( new whatever );
        A = ptr_a.get();
        B = ptr_b.get();
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<whatever> ptr_a;
    std::shared_ptr<whatever> ptr_b;
};
```

then in the function you go:

```
whatever * A, * B;
Shallocator { A, B };

// no headaches
```

Memory will be freed when the lifetime of the Shallocator ends.